# BugSense responding with status code 500 on iOS on a phonegap application

Tags: ios, cordova, nsexception, bugsense

I am developing a phonegap application for iOS devices. I also integrated bugsense for iOS.

I am using window.onError from javascript to catch errors and then use a Webview delegate method to perform exception handling. This is where I create a custom NSException object and use BUGSENSE_LOG() method to log exception. But that is not working. This is the error that I get:

```
 BugSense --> Server responded with status code: 500
```

This is my code:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Source", @"Phonegap ios", nil];

NSException *exc = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"MyException" reason:completeMessage userInfo:myDictionary];    
//[exc raise];
BUGSENSE_LOG(exc, @"Tag");
```

I have turned the debugger off and I am making a release build. I have checked my settings as well and everything seems as per the guidelines given on the Bugsense official website.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Hi I am the Bugsense CEO. Thank you a lot for taking the time investigate PhoneGap support in iOS. We are working on a PhoneGap JS plugin and what think is more important is the onFailure callbacks. I would be glad to talk further on this issue. I can be reach at panos@ you know where :)

Comment: @PanosJee Thank you for the response. It took some time but I was finally able to achieve what I wanted. It still has some issues though. For now, we have something to work with but it'd be really nice if there is an official plugin for phonegap. I'd love to talk further on this issue. Will contact you for sure! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WELL .. I was able to find the solution to my own problem. All I did was instead of creating the NSException object, I raised an exception, caught it and then logged it. Surprisingly it worked..

```
 @try {
    [NSException raise:@"MyException" format:@"%@,%@,%@",message,url,lineNumber];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {        
    BUGSENSE_LOG(exception, @"tag");
}
```

Comment: This workaround worked for me, but it's very bad and ugly. bug sense must fix it!

Answer (score 0):

please look into this that was reported by Bug sense Guys. See the URL
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/9JasIb4Jlg4

Hi guys, thanks for bringing it up. We have started experimenting with PhoneGap but we had found the following issue.
window.onerror was not working on Android so we could not have a global uncaught exception handler.
Then we thought of creating a Bugsense callback that you could add to the onerror callbacks of Phonegap.

If you have any suggestions we would be more than happy to listen to them. We are also publishing the structure of our api so that you can create your own plugins.
Btw, we have some HTML5 support 
https://github.com/soundcloud/Bugsense-js
https://github.com/crcn/mesh-bugsense